# Query to get values of one table which are not there in string column of another table, also less than a particular datetime value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables :

```
mysql> select * from quizquestionbank;

| ID | QuestionFilePath | CorrectAnswer | EndDate            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | p.wav            |             1 |2014-05-12 12:00:00 |
|  2 | q.wav            |             2 |2014-05-12 12:00:00 |
|  3 | a.wav            |             3 |2014-05-12 12:00:00 |
|  4 | b.wav            |             1 |2014-05-12 12:00:00 |
|  5 | m.wav            |             3 |2014-05-12 12:00:00 |
```

Second table is :

```
mysql> select * from quizuserdetails;

| ID | MSISDN | QuestionIdDetails | AnswerRecord |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 235346 | 1,3,4,5           | S,F,S,F      |
|  2 | 564574 | 4,5,67,88         | F,S,F,s      |
|  3 | 500574 | 5,55,66,44,2      | F,F,F,F      |
```

I want to get the IDs from table 1 which :
 1. are not there in QuestionIdDetails column of second table and
 2. less than current date and time.

Following Query gives me records required for first point:

```
Select qb.ID,qb.EndDate 
from quizquestionbank qb 
     left join quizuserdetails qd 
     on find_in_set(qb.id, QuestionIdDetails) > 0  
     and msisdn = '235346' 
where qd.id is null
```

But for second requirement following query gives error :

```
Select * 
from predictionfootball 
where '2014-05-10 00:00:00' < 
    (Select qb.ID,qb.EndDate 
    from quizquestionbank qb 
         left join quizuserdetails qd 
         on find_in_set(qb.id, QuestionIdDetails) > 0  
         and msisdn = '235346' 
    where qd.id is null)
```

Please tell me the way to do it.

Comment: If you want to run such queries, structure your database using junction/association tables.  Do not store lists of things in comma-delimited lists.  It is like breaking your leg to run a marathon -- SQL supports tables for storing lists of things, not strings.

Comment: what the error you got ?

Comment: @Gordon I just dont want to increase my table size.
With one MSISDN i will be having hundred of values in QuestionIdDetails  also i will be having thousands of msisdns
So i thought to keep QuestionIdDetails   values comma-delimited.

Kindly clarify how is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
 Select qb.ID,qb.EndDate 
 from quizquestionbank qb 
 left join quizuserdetails qd 
 on find_in_set(qb.id, QuestionIdDetails) > 0  
 and msisdn = '235346' 
 where qd.id is null
 AND qb.EndDate < '2014-05-10 00:00:00'    ------> added this line
```